# Git: Split subdirectory into repo and continue merging

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a Github repository structured the following way

```
repo1
  |--- dir1
  |--- dir2
  |--- dir3
```

I am splitting each of the directories into its own repo. I was able to do that following the instructions [here](http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/moving-a-subdirectory-into-a-separate-git-repository/).

But after the split I still have to deal with short span of time where commits will continue going into `repo1`. How can I keep merging these commits to individual dir repos without overwriting changes in the dir repos?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that now you have main (old) repo with subfolders, and also new repos on a different path.

For each incoming commit

1. In main repo checkout to the updated branch (so that working tree has the updated files)
2. In each subdirectory repo do `git --work-tree=/path/to/main/repo/subfolder add -A .` This adds changes to the stage of that repo.
3. `git commit -m'message'`

Comment: it is `dev` branch and the directories are not submodules.

Comment: I would prefer not to lose the commit history of changes made to `repo1`.

Comment: This should not change the commit history of repo1. You just 'borrow' files from it to dir-repos.

Comment: I meant I would like carry over the commit history of `dir1` in  `repo1` into `dir1Repo` event after `dir1` was split. For example, if `dir1Repo` was created out of `dir1` when the `HEAD` commit hash of `repo1` was `12345A`. After that commit `12345B` and `12345C` were made into `dir1` in `repo1`. Doing the command you suggested would get me changes part of 2 commits in `dir1Repo` but I would lose `12345B` and `12345C` from `dir1Repo` commit history.